# CSS: Place text at beginning of centered headline

Tags: html, css, position, centering

I want to place a short texte at the beginning of a centered headline.
My current solution is to have a container with display inline arround the headline 
and placing the text with text right and display block.

This works pretty good until the I have a long headline.

The HTML:

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="headline-container">
    <span class="headline-companion">FooBar</span>
    <h3>Sample Headline</h3>
  </div>  
</div>
```

THE SCSS:

```
.article{
  display:block;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.headline-container{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;

  h3{
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline; 
  }

  .headline-companion{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwNJGy

Are there any solutions where I don't have to position the text with absolute?

**Clarification**:
I want that the Short text beggins always at the first letter of the headline no matter how long the centered headline is.

[image: Example of different length headline]

Comment: Are you looking to make sure the short text above the header is aligned with the beginning of the header?

Comment: Yes the short text above should always be at the begging of the text of the headline

Comment: The problem seems to stem from that the `h3`'s parent (`.headline-container`) is not collapsing to the width of the `h3` when it wraps. As to why, I'm not particularly sure but this may give you some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like what (I think) you want to do can be accomplished if you wrap your `<h3>` tag in another element and set a `max-width` value, and by specifying `word-wrap.`

This allows you to change the width of the parent divs, or length of the header text without having very negative effects on the overall formatting:

**[Edit]:** In addition, another element needs to be added if you want to have the `headline-companion` and headline centered with respect to `article` but with left justified text... in this case `sub-headline-container.`

```css
.article {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.headline-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.headline-wrap {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: left;
}
.headline-companion {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <div class="headline-container">
    <div class="sub-headline-container">

      <span class="headline-companion">FooBar</span>

      <div class="headline-wrap">
        <h3>
        Sample Headline
      </h3>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="article">
  <div class="headline-container">
    <div class="sub-headline-container">

      <span class="headline-companion">FooBar</span>

      <div class="headline-wrap">
        <h3>
       SUUUUUUPPPPERRRRRRRR BIG HEADLINE!!! ------------------------------- --------------
      </h3>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a clarification I want the headline-companion text always at the first letter of the headline.

Comment: This works and Headline continues on the right after the line break even better!